# Angular 8: Can't correctly get value from service

Tags: angular, service, rxjs, local-storage, subscription

I'm having a simple auth service just for testing as I'm learning Angular which sets a localStorage value

GeneralService:

```
isAuthenticated = new Subject();
autoLogin = new Subject();
```

AuthenticationService:

```
if (response.message === 'Logged in') {
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', '1');
    this.generalS.isAuthenticated.next(true);
  } else {
    this.generalS.isAuthenticated.next(false);
  }
```

auth component

```
isAuthSub: Subscription;
// in the submit function ...
this.authS.login(userData);
this.isAuthSub = this.generalS.isAuthenticated.subscribe( (data) => {
  if (data) {
    console.log('Yes');
    this.route.navigate(['recipes']);
  } else {
    console.log('No');
  }
});
```

In the console I get `Yes`

In app component

```
const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
if (!isLoggedIn || isLoggedIn !== '1') {
  this.generalS.autoLogin.next(false);
  this.generalS.isAuthenticated.next(false);
} else {
  console.log('loggenInValue: ' + isLoggedIn);
  this.generalS.autoLogin.next(true);
  this.generalS.isAuthenticated.next(true);
}
```

And I get this in the console

```
loggenInValue: 1
```

So the autoLogin and isAuthenticated subjects should be holding `true` as a value

I listen th this value in the header component to display or hide the `login` link but it doesn't log anything

In header component

```
authSub: Subscription;
isAuthenticated: boolean;
ngOnInit() {
  this.authSub = this.generalS.isAuthenticated.subscribe( (data: boolean) => {
    this.isAuthenticated = data;
    console.log('authenticated: ' + data);
  });
}
```

I don't get any log from this section. Any ideas regarding solving this issue?
[I know I shouldn't check the autologin feature like this but just for testing to check the localStorage value and change other values depending on it]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't know where the code is at exactly in your authService. I'm assuming you're calling next() before you subscribe, which means there aren't any Subscribers yet. Subjects only emit events to existing Subscribers, not future ones.

You can easily switch to ReplaySubject if your interested in just getting the most recent value on subscription:

```
isAuthenticated = new ReplaySubject(1);
autoLogin = new ReplaySubject(1);
```

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject

Comment: in app component I already get the localStorage value and it's correct then I use "next" to set the value in the service then in the header component I subscribe and fetch it. Is this wrong?

Comment: When you call next(), you aren't "setting" a value. You are emitting a value. So if no one is subscribed or listening, they don't get your value. It's kinda like that saying: If a tree falls in an empty forest does it make a sound? Sort of like that. If you use my suggestion, it'l replay the last value you emitted to new subscribers.

Comment: I applied this and it's working fine. Thanks a lot.